# On each click Incresing console error no : Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function

Tags: jquery

On each click `a.ui-tabs-anchor` html code generating and increasing error rapidly like a bellow snippet.

[image: console-error]

Bellow snippet code i am using to stop ui tab on click them.I have searched through the web but i didn't find any solution.
If any body have any idea to resolve this let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.ui-tabs-anchor').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
       $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top().stop(true,false)
       }, 0);
        return false;
       }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It should be: `target.offset().top`  I'm not sure btw why you want to use `.stop()` method here but then, it should be `target.stop(true,false).offset().top`. FYI, error means than `top` property isn't a function

Comment: can you please post your html code

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to chain `stop()` to a value getter method. Since the value getter doesn't return a jQuery object you can't do this.

Try changing :

```
target.offset().top().stop(true,false)
```

To:

```
target.stop(true,false).offset().top
```

Also note that `top()` is not a function. `offset()` returns an object with properties `top` and `left`

Comment: after adding this code scroll is not working can you please check my site to

Comment: No, please create a sandbox demo that replicates problem like in jsfiddle.net. We have no access to trying to adjust code on your site and I don't want to have to try to figure out where in the files the code is